# Why is my loop device size 0?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Why is my loop device not 600G in size?

```
$ fallocate --length 600G sysvol
$ sudo losetup --find sysvol
$ sudo losetup --all 
/dev/loop0: [0831]:13 (/.../sysvol)

$ sudo losetup --set-capacity /dev/loop0
$ sudo stat /dev/loop0
  File: ‘/dev/loop0’
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   block special file
Device: 5h/5d   Inode: 51          Links: 1     Device type: 7,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stat` is not the right tool to investigate block devices.

Here is an example of using `--set-capacity`:

```
root@maxim:~# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/loop0
0
root@maxim:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/aaa.img count=10 bs=1M
10+0 записей получено
10+0 записей отправлено
скопировано 10485760 байт (10 MB), 0,00709284 c, 1,5 GB/c
root@maxim:~# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/loop0
0
root@maxim:~# losetup --find /tmp/aaa.img 
root@maxim:~# losetup -l
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE
/dev/loop0         0      0         0  0 /tmp/aaa.img
root@maxim:~#
root@maxim:~# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/loop0
10485760
root@maxim:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/aaa.img count=10 bs=1M oflag=append conv=notrunc
10+0 записей получено
10+0 записей отправлено
скопировано 10485760 байт (10 MB), 0,00771261 c, 1,4 GB/c
root@maxim:~# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/loop0
10485760
root@maxim:~# losetup --set-capacity /dev/loop0
root@maxim:~# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/loop0
20971520
root@maxim:~#
```

Comment: if I can't change its capacity, what is the `--set-capacity loopdev` option meant for? It seem to be what I need: "reread size of the  file  associated  with the specified loop device". I can create a loopback filesystem successfully, but I need to operate on a device, not on a filesystem.

Comment: according to manpage  --set-capacity force the loop driver to reread the size of the **file** associated with the specified loop device. So you should run sudo _losetup --set-capacity sysvol_ instead of _losetup --set-capacity /dev/loop0_ and if you mount sysvol you should see 600G free space

Comment: As the manpage says, you specify the _loop device_, and it looks at the _associated file_. You can see the associated file with `losetup -a`: you don't specify the file, `losetup` knows the association. Giving the file as parameter results in `Inappropriate ioctl for device`. 
I see that I'm off track with `stat` though. It reports 0 size for my other devices like `sdb1` as well. 
I need to operate on the device, not on a filesystem. If I format the device and mount it, the mounted fs has the correct size. But if I try to operate on the device, insufficient size is reported.

Comment: i've updated answer. I think _stat_ command is misused against block devices.

Comment: Yes, I also saw that `stat` is the wrong tool for looking at block devices. Thanks for the detail! `blockdev` shows the correct size, so the issue is not with `losetup`.